# Sort table header using Orderby in Angular 2

Tags: angular, sorting, tableheader

I am so new to Angular and I’m learning it from some tutorials on the internet.
Now I want to learn how to sort table header of table of my heroes using orderby. I don’t understand pipe and how to call it from the component. 
I just don’t understand how to use pipe. I don’t understand when they explained this in the tutorials. Can someone please explain this to me so I can understand what is really happening? I don’t understand the transform method. Here is my code, can you see what is wrong? Thanks in advance

```
Superheroes.component.html
enter code here`
    <tr *ngFor="let hero of heroes | orderBy:['-hero.id', 'hero.name',
            '-hero.phone-number', 'hero.country']"> 

I generated the pipe, but it is not working.

Orderby.pipe.ts
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'orderby', pure: false })

export class OrderbyPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(heroes: any[], name: string): any[]  {

    heroes.sort((a: any, b: any) => {

      if (a[name] < b[name]) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a[name] > b[name]) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
    return heroes;
  }
}


    Superheros.component.ts
    import { Component, OnInit, Pipe, PipeTransform, Input } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

    import { OrderbyPipe } from '../orderby.pipe';

    import { Heroes } from '../model/hero';
    import { HeroService } from '../services/hero.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-superheroes',
      templateUrl: './superheroes.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./superheroes.component.css'],
      providers: [HeroService],

    })

    export class SuperheroesComponent implements OnInit {

      isValidFormSubmitted: boolean = null;
      searchForm = null;
      statusmessage: string = "Nothing submitted";

      //records: Array<any>;
      isDesc: boolean = false;
      column: string = 'Name';
      direction: number;
      heroes: Hero[];

      constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.searchForm = new FormGroup({
          searchmode: new FormControl('', Validators.required)

        });

      //  this.setDefaultValues();
        this.getHeroes();
      }

      getHeroes(): void {
        this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
      }

      sort(property) {
        this.isDesc = !this.isDesc;
        this.column = name;
        this.direction = this.isDesc ? 1 : -1;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Think of it as a real pipe. You have got some stuff, press it through a pipe and out comes stuff again... just maybe looks a bit different than before. Depending on how the pipe looks the content will be transformed.

Comment: You can use `material angular`s `sort header` component, check this: https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview

Answer (score 0):

First, the pipe you made use a string[] as argument, not only a string.
Second, you can not use a[name], see https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe.
You can use some like

```
//use <tr *ngFor="let hero of heroes | orderBy:'name'">
export class OrderbyPipe implements PipeTransform {

transform(heroes: any[], name: string): any[]  {
  if (name=='name'){
     heroes.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
     return a.name==b.name?0:a.name<b.name?-1:1;
  }
  return heroes;
}
```

Comment: I made the change the sort is not being preformed? I think it got something to do with   <tr *ngFor="let hero of heroes | orderBy:'name'"> and the component.ts file.

Comment: In your app.module you must include the pipper in "declarations" @NgModule({
    imports: [..],declarations: [orderby,...]],providers: [..],bootstrap:[AppComponent]})

Answer (score 0):

```
My app.module.ts is like this.

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators,  } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { OrderbyPipe } from './orderby.pipe';
import { SuperherosComponent } from './superheros/superheros.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'superheros', component: SuperherosComponent }

  ];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    OrderbyPipe,
    SuperherosComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes)

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],

})
export class AppModule { }
```